# Build targets for Linux static library

Tags: linux, gcc

I am developing a C++ library for x86 or x64 Linux server programmers. The library is not open sourced and the compiled output shall be static library(.a) files.

Which build targets should I consider for most server programmers? So far, I am considering these:

- GCC and CLANG
- x86, x86_64
- debug (assert is turned on, no optimized code), release (assert is turned off) [1]

The total combination shall be 2*2*2 = 8.

Are these enough? Should I consider Ubuntu and CentOS?

---

[1] I have used assert() instead of run-time junction (code below) only for some performance-sensitive functions. In other cases, I use runtime junction. Runtime junction is more needed for production code, but it cause performance impact to very frequently called functions. For example, executing two junction instructions and accessing m_length takes longer time than accessing array data only.

```
#define runtime_assert(x); { if (g_enableAssert && !(x)) ShowError(#x); }

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define assert(x) runtime_assert(x)
#else
#define assert(x) 0
#endif

bool g_enableAssert = true;

class Array
{
    int m_length;

    // doing runtime junction
    void Set(int index, int value)
    {
        runtime_assert(index>=0 && index<m_length);
        ...
    }

    // using assert
    void Set(int index, int value)
    {
        assert(index>=0 && index<m_length);
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears you are asking us to tell you what systems your users use.  Polls are off-topic on SO.  Ask your users.

Comment: Which Linux system do you consider canonical if you aren't already taking Ubuntu and CentOS into account as Linux systems.  (And yes, there's a subtle pun lurking in my question.)

Comment: Are all assertions backed by non-assertive tests for the invalid conditions that trigger an error handling path?  If not, are you sure you want production code to blunder on when there's a problem that an assert would detect and protect you against and removing the assert means your code will behave erroneously?  Will 'assert turned off' replace the `abort()` action with a raised exception, for example?

Comment: Modified the question.

Comment: Use the standard [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) which is disabled by the `-DNDEBUG` preprocessor flag.

Comment: Yes, I am already using it. I added the code snippet above for more understanding.